# Fill a mesh with another mesh using geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I need to fill the volume of a mesh in a procedural way with instances of another mesh in the geometry node editor.
I'm not sure if it's possible, can anyone help me with a potential node tree?

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify "fill" - do you want to pack cubes with random rotations? as if you physically poured them in? That can only be done with physics. You can design a pattern of cubes to fill the volume, but considering the arbitrary shape of the pot it's rather non-trivial.